# Moving the file pointer of a disk with SetFilePointerEx

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to move the file pointer of a disk to a specific offset(file's last cluster) using `SetFilePointerEx()`. The calculated offset is found with:

```
LARGE_INTEGER dist;
dist.QuadPart = (output1.QuadPart * dwBytesPerSect) + ((lastExtent + lengthOfExtent - 1) * totalClusterSize);
BOOL res = SetFilePointerEx(hDevice, dist, nullptr, FILE_BEGIN);
if (!res){
    // handle error
    DWORD error = GetLastError();
    cout<<GetLastError()<<endl;
    cout << "'There is an error with SetFilePointerEX" << endl;
}
cout<<"This is the SetFilePointer distance: \n\n"<<dist.QuadPart;
```

Then I use `Readfile()` to read off the last 4k cluster block:

```
DWORD nRead;
unsigned char *buff;
buff = new unsigned char[totalClusterSize];

BOOL fileFromVol = ReadFile(hDevice,   //C drive
                buff,
                4096,
                &nRead,
                NULL);

if (fileFromVol == 0){         //Error handling
    cout << "Error with fileFromVol" << "\n\n";
    DWORD error = GetLastError();
    cout<<error<<endl;
        if (error == ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED){
            cout << "error_access_denied"<<endl;
        }
}
cout<<"\n\n"<<buff<<"\n\n";
memset(buff,NULL,4096);
```

So my file offset `dist.QuadPart` is always constant but my read buffer(`buff`) changes hexadecimal values every time I run my program on the same file.

First run example:

```
This is the SetFilePointer distance:

3689362889266376704

008F4264
```

Second run example:

```
This is the SetFilePointer distance:

3689362889266376704

00E53CE8
```

Any ideas why it keeps changing?

For my next step, I need to write zero's to the cluster. Can I use `memset()` to write zeros on the last cluster location?

Comment: Are you not just printing out the address of `buff[0]`? Why wouldn't it change each time?

Comment: I'm trying to read data off of the last cluster of a specified file(like a text file) shouldn't the data stay the same if I'm not modifying the file?

Comment: A couple points: you should not be hard-coding the cluster size to 4096. You need to get the cluster size for the volume you're working on (sectors per cluster * bytes per sector) and use that value to allocate the cluster buffer and perform the read. Also, your cluster buffer is an array of 4096 `int`s (so 16KB on x86) - it should be an array of bytes.

Comment: You're not printing the data from the file. You're printing the address of a stack-allocated buffer. Due various factors (such as ASLR) the address of that buffer can change every time you run the program or call the function.

Comment: So for the array I should use unsigned char [sectors per cluster * bytes per sector]? How can I tell if I'm reading data from the same file handle? My next step would be to write data into the file offset but I don't want to write data to the wrong place(a system file).

Comment: I'm not sure why this post keeps getting downvoted. What's wrong with the question and what can I do to improve it?

Comment: You're being downvoted because it looks like you're trying to learn to write a program by posting the latest revision of your code to SO every time you encounter a new problem. SO does not take well to these sorts of beginner questions.

Comment: Ah I see, but my post are usually on a different portion of the program. So I guess I can only have 1 question per project. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value you are printing out is the address of the buffer, rather than its contents. And the address of the buffer is not fixed. Of course, arguing about why the address of the buffer can change is a little moot since you actually want to print out the buffer's contents.

Print out the first element of the array like this:

```
cout<<"\n\n"<<buff[0]<<"\n\n";
```

And you should see values read from the disk.

Some other comments:

1. Don't hard code the buffer size. You have to ensure that it is a multiple of the sector size.
2. Your buffer should be of type `unsigned char*` rather than `unsigned int*`.
3. Check the value `nRead` in case the buffer is only partially filled.

Comment: I changed the buffer to: <br></br>unsigned char *buff;
 buff = new unsigned char[totalClusterSize];<br></br>
The value of nRead says 0 when I cout it. my cout for buff[0] is '=' for each file I try it on. Not sure what that means.

Comment: It means that no bytes were read. Lots of possible reasons for that.

Comment: Any common places to check for read errors?

Comment: Check that you can read from the beginning first. Then read all the documentation carefully. CreateFile and ReadFile. This from CreateFile docs may be relevant: *Note  To read or write to the last few sectors of the volume, you must call DeviceIoControl and specify FSCTL_ALLOW_EXTENDED_DASD_IO. This signals the file system driver not to perform any I/O boundary checks on partition read or write calls. Instead, boundary checks are performed by the device driver.*

Comment: Ok so I think I might be doing this wrong. As of now I have 2 DevicIoControl calls. The first DeviceIoControl has control code `FSCTL_GET_RETRIEVAL_POINTERS` to find out extent information on the file extents. The second DeviceIoControl calls `FSCTL_GET_RETRIEVAL_POINTER_BASE` to find out infomartion on the drive regarding the vcn (since we can't assume it starts at 0). Should I call it a third time with `FSCTL_ALLOW_EXTENDED_DASD_IO` and should my second call be to file handle and not the drive handle?

Comment: I'm not sure. Can you read from the beginning of the volume?

Comment: If I set the nNumberOfBytesToRead to 4096 and take out SetFilePointerEx() then nRead comes out to 4096 after ReadFile() and the buff[0] comes out to a weird symbol that looks like a lowercase delta

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure that `FSCTL_ALLOW_EXTENDED_DASD_IO` is really what you need. I also have no idea how you are working out how to set the file pointer. We only have fragments of code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55736/discussion-between-dspaces1-and-david-heffernan).